# Namespaces on Nokogiri's xml output

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to isolate part of a xml document that uses namespaces, using nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml= "<s:Some xmlns:s=\"http://nmsc.com/nmsc\"><s:One></s:One></s:Some>"
n= Nokogiri.XML(xml)
n.xpath("//s:One", :s=>"http://nmsc.com/nmsc")[0].to_xml
```

This disregards the namespace and simply outputs

```
"<s:One/>"
```

How can I generate the XML with the correct namespace, i.e.:

```
<s:One xmlns:s="http://nmsc.com/nmsc" />
```

?

What's interesting is that the namespace is there:

```
> n.xpath("//s:One", :s=>"http://nmsc.com/nmsc")[0]
=> #(Element:0x3fb1a05d0ed0 {
  name = "One",
  namespace = #(Namespace:0x3fb1a05d1fc4 {
    prefix = "s",
    href = "http://nmsc.com/nmsc"
    })
  })
```

but `to_xml` doesn't include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a new XML document and add the selected node to it the namespace info will be included:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
xml = "<s:Some xmlns:s=\"http://nmsc.com/nmsc\"><s:One></s:One></s:Some>"
n = Nokogiri.XML(xml)
selected = n.xpath("//s:One", :s=>"http://nmsc.com/nmsc")[0]

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
doc.root = selected
puts doc.to_xml
```

output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:One xmlns:s="http://nmsc.com/nmsc"/>
```

Comment: So `nokogiri` is avoiding outputting the namespace because it detects the element is part of another document (on which it is defined)? That makes sense, thank you!